# Why does SQL Server resume mirroring after server is restarted?

Tags: sql-server, mirroring

I paused database mirroring before I rebooted the Windows server, and I found that the database had resumed mirroring automatically after the reboot.

This is not what I want--I want to resume it manually after I do some verification.  Is it normal for database mirroring to resume automatically after a reboot, even if it was paused prior to the reboot?

Answer (score 4):

> Is that normal?

This is the default behavior to automatically resume mirroring when the mirror comes up (provided no errors encountered). It will be in suspended state if there is a REDO error.

> I want to resume it manually after my verification...

If it resumes by itself then everything is good. You dont have to worry. If it does not then there is a problem and you will start troubleshooting.

Comment: Thank you Kin, If I want to re-enable the mirroring after restart server. The only way is -- I need to remove the mirroring first? and rebuild mirroring after? Can instance  just stay suspended status?

Comment: I dont see a need on what you are asking. Unless you do a force_allow_dataloss it will resume automatically (or if there is a redo error). If you want to rebuild mirroring, then yes, you have to turn it off and then re-establish it again by a full and then a tlog backup.

Comment: @kin - I believe you can break the mirror and re-establish it again by restoring the transaction log backups that occurred after you broke the mirror - no need to restore the full database as it's already there. Make sure you leave it in a restoring state though.

Comment: That is correct .. provided log backup chain is intact and not broken.